# How to load-and-launch a Google Chrome App from the command line?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

[At this link](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app#open), it says:

> These command line options to Chrome may help you iterate:
>
> `--load-and-launch-app=/path/to/app/` installs the unpacked application from the given path, and launches it.

**What is the entire command line statement?**

For example, is it:

```
$ chrome --load-and-launch-app=/path/to/app/
```

or maybe:

```
$ cca --load-and-launch-app=/path/to/app/
```

What, specifically, is the entire command?

Comment: Are you basically asking what your particular distribution named your praticular version of Chrome / Chromium? _We have no idea_.

Comment: @xan: I don't understand what you mean. Could you please explain your comment a little more? I don't *think* that's really my question. But I could be wrong. Apparently, I don't know or understand enough to realize that your rephrasing of my question is what I really meant to ask. Presumably, that's part of my confusion and why I have this question in the first place. Please help and explain: ***What is this information you write about? And how would I use it to answer my question?***

Comment: Okay, I read your question as: "Is it `chrome`, `cca`, or something else?" It very highly depends on your system and the Chrome/Chromium version used. I can be `chrome`, it can be `chromium`, it can be `google-chrome-stable`, it can be something else. There isn't enough information about your setup to answer.

Comment: @xan: I am using a Mac, OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, Chrome version 47.0.2526.80 (64-bit). Is that enough information? Or is more info needed? Is there anywhere I can go to look this up? Perhaps there is a terminal command that might tell me? What search terms could I use to do a Google search? Can you point me to any documentation?

Comment: This basically answers your question for all platforms: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags Or this: http://superuser.com/questions/157484/start-google-chrome-on-mac-with-command-line-switches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic command you have correct

```
/Path/to/Chrome --load-and-launch-app=/Path/to/App
```

Assuming you are using Mac, OSX(from your comments) and you installed Google Chrome the normal way, (into your Applications directory), your /Path/to/Chrome will be

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

But to make sure you can [image: Drag and Drop] your Google Chrome Application directly into your terminal (assuming standard MacOSX terminal or iTerm)

For the /Path/To/App part of the command, use the directory which contains the *manifest.json* file.
For instance, if your path to the *manifest.json* file is

```
/Users/[Your Username]/Downloads/basic/manifest.json
```

which you can get from going to this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/bookmarks/basic.zip)

Your command to load and launch the "Basic" google chrome app is

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --load-and-launch-app=/Users/[Your Username]/Downloads/basic
```

Answer (score 2):

One additional detail that may be helpful: the path to your app must be an absolute path, beginning at the root directory (`/`).

You have to do `--load-and-launch-app=/Users/YourUsername/Documents/my_chrome_app`

Alternately, if you don't want to type the whole path, you could use `$PWD`, which evaluates to your current directory (must execute the command from the same directory as your manifest.json):
`--load-and-launch-app=$PWD`

You cannot do `--load-and-launch-app=.` 
You cannot do `--load-and-launch-app=~/Documents/my_chrome_app`